# Washing machine drain hose maximum length

Tags: drain

I am moving washing machine 6 ft from its current position. Do I have to relocate the drain or can I simply get a longer drain hose and run it inside the wall to the existing drain position?

Comment: Have you checked the manual for your machine to see if it says anything about drain hose length?

Answer (score 1):

### Given your question, you have to move the drain.

You *cannot* put the drain hose *in the wall* and pass plumbing code. It's not suitable for installation in a wall.

Thus, you need to move the drain using proper pipe, properly installed for the purpose.

*In some other situation where the hose would merely go 6 feet more, out of the wall, it might or might not be OK, depending on your washer installation instructions.*